# How to get the hidden input's value by using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, input, hidden

In angularjs,I want to get the value of the hidden input.  such as the following:

```
<pre>
<input type="hidden" name="captId" value="AqXpRshs9QHfxUbOWqMT" ng-model="captId">
</pre>
```

How to get the "hidden input" value "AqXpRshs9QHfxUbOWqMT"  by using angularjs,not ajax or jquery.

Comment: `document.getElementById("captId").value`

Comment: it's far better using an input type text with display:none

Answer (score 24):

You can use `ng-init` to initialize the value so it binds that to your model variable upon creation.

```
<input type="hidden" name="captId" ng-init="captId='AqXpRshs9QHfxUbOWqMT'" ng-model="captId">
```

---

Or you can get it directly if all else fails:

```
angular.element(document.getElementsByName('captId')[0]).val();
// or dont use angular at all
document.getElementsByName('captId')[0].value
```

[Documentation for angular.element](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Comment: the second way you mention is much better

Comment: @PascalLeMerrer agreed, I think if op was to use the first method he/she might find that the value is set to an empty string because it would be overwritten with the `captID` value which is likely blank.

Answer (score 1):

**By ID**

```
document.getElementById('yourId').value
```

**By Name**

```
document.getElementsByName('yourName')[0].value
```

Keep it simple :)

Comment: Your by name should be: `document.getElementsByName('yourName')[0].value` since since the [getElementsByName returns a collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)